# ¿Cómo ocultar progreso de operación con yfinance?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, conda

Al ejecutar este script cuyo objeto es la importación de cotizaciones desde Yahoo Finances, se puede evitar que me presente como resultado, el DataFrame y tambienlas líneas que advierten del final de la importación de cada conjunto de datos importados de Yahoo?. Deseo que solamente me presente del DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", 
                "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50",  
                "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", 
                'AAPL':"Apple", 'MSFT':"Microsoft", 'GOOG':"Google", 'SAN':'Santander', 'REP.MC': 'Repsol', 
               'GOOG': 'Google', 'BBVA': 'B_Bilbao', 'SPY': 'SPY', '^GSPC': 'SP500', '^VIX':'VIX'}
tickers = dicc_tickers.keys()
names = dicc_tickers.values()
stocks = (
    (pd.concat(
        [yf.download(ticker, start= start_day, end = end_day)[
            'Adj Close'
        ].rename(dicc_tickers[ticker])
        for ticker in tickers],
        axis=1,
        sort=True)
    )
)
df_indices = stocks.loc[:,~stocks.columns.duplicated()]
df_indices[:3]
```

Devuelve:

[image: salida del script]

Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada más pasa el keyword argument `progress=False` a `yf.download`.

```python
yf.download(ticker, start= start_day, end = end_day, progress=False)
```